# TFS Check In History

Tags: tfs

I am trying to find out the most recent branch/merge for my project (I'm migrating to a new server and want to define a starting changeset).  Is there a way for me to either query the repository database or the command line tools to find out the most recent branch/merge?

Comment: Do you need to do this on a file by file basis, or for the whole team project?  When you say "branch" do you mean "branch into" this project, or times when this project was branched into other folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the history of a current folder by using the `history` command.

Lets assume your entire project resides in a directory called 'project'.  Using the below command will give you a list of all the changesets that impacted that directory or any of its children.

```
tf history project /r
```